# wrong og:description

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-opengraph

Facebook does not get information from description Open Graph tags 
I do get following error but not for description field

> The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can
>   be inferred from other tags.

I do have in header (Wordpress)

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(the_excerpt()); ?>" />
```

bugzilla shows correct source of the page

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<p>3D organs modeled for real-time DVD application</p>" />
```

But on fb page description shown is 
JavaScript code from google analytics :)

> "var _gaq = _gaq || []; _gaq.push(['_setAccount'..."

Do you spot the error somewhere?

By the way... I know fb caches information... is there a way to reset it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To refresh the cache run the url through Facebooks URL Linter here http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug. What is the url you are trying to parse?

Comment: I ran it but it is still the same. For example this url [link](http://milosparipovic.com/index.php/jim-parsons/)  ; If you look at source you can see it is totally different image and if you click on like, page description displays garbage even though og:description has normal text

Comment: og:fb:app_id should be fb:app_id. You only need one of fb:app_id or fb:admins. The open graph markup works without the rest of the head material there and no <p></p>. No meta tags should have no html markup <p></p>. Plus when I run your page with just the head and nothing in the body I get a ' showing up on page.

Comment: Found the line interferring. Line 14 of the code: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://milosparipovic.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/css/thumb.reel.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />, has a ' at the end.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much! I looked it 500 times over and did not notice that.

Comment: running the url through the Linter solved this for me. Does anyone know if running through the linter refreshes for the whole domain?

Comment: @afxjzs Unfortunately it does not. You have to lint each url separately

Comment: That worked! The "Scraped URL" link (at the bottom) was particularly useful to detect a sneaky character that disrupted the layout.