# Image and text meta data tags not recognised in Facebook/Stumbleupon etc

Tags: facebook, wordpress, url, facebook-opengraph

This is doing my head in! I've searched about for answers everywhere but with no success.

**I believe my issue is on the same lines as this question asked:**
[wrong og:description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627705/wrong-ogdescription) 
[facebook is not recognizing my meta tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109973/facebook-is-not-recognizing-my-meta-tags)

**Wordpress Website:** http://www.cyclingabout.com

All I want is to have image and text data visible in Facebook. I'd like the start of my post and an image from my post to be displayed when someone 'likes' or 'shares' my post.

I have played around with a few plugins that attempt to make this work. I have "facebook like thumbnail" which does add an image when someone likes it as it is supposed to, but doesn't solve the text problem (or do anything about sharing). I have also tried "Facebook Open Graph Meta in WordPress" however this doesn't appear to solve my problem.

Is there an issue with my coding or a widget which is blocking this information?

**I have run a Facebook Linter check and I get the following:**

Inferred Property: The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. 
Inferred Property: The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

I have searched ways to resolve these og issues with no success.

I'd love to hear from someone! Any ideas?

Kind regards

Alex

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the HTML returned from your page and I see this:

`<meta property="og:description" content="description" />`

`<meta property="og:description" content="" />`

Are you using two different og tag plugins?

Figure out how to get rid of the second one with the empty content and also specify the og:url one and I'd say you'd be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I deleted everything associated with meta tags in my dashboard. I also restored the original header from my themes CSS.

I am still getting no love from Facebook, with the linter saying the same 'inferred property' message as before on all links.

I have just created another website with this theme and the meta data is working flawlessly. 

Any other ideas?

Comment: As you've already just troubleshot, your issue appears to be a corrupted theme.  Start from scratch like you did with the other site.